# How to match multiple groups on a specific line in Perl, but not other lines?

Tags: regex, perl, grouping

I understand the /g flag and I'm able to match a pattern multiple times, but I'm having a difficult time researching this particular question.

Say my string has multiple lines and I want to match a grouped pattern on a line that contains a specific word, but not on a different line that doesn't.

For an example string `$test` with multiple lines

```
Unimportant line.
Important line with !special1! word and !special2! word. 
Extra line with !special3! word and !special4! word.
```

I want to print the two specials on the important line but not the extra line, so the result would be:

```
special1, special2
```

I can match *every* special using /g

```
my @both = $test =~ /!(.+?)!/g;
print join(', ', @both);
```

But the output is:

```
special1, special2, special3, special4
```

If I try to include the word 'Important'

```
my @both = $test =~ /Important.+?!(.+?)!/g;
print join(', ', @both);
```

I just get

```
special1
```

I understand it only matches once because 'Important' only occurs once, but I can't figure out  how to get the output

```
special1, special2
```

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple lines containing `Important`?

Comment: @Borodin Hmm, I guess in my use case there will only ever be a single line

Comment: @Borodin Actually I'm curious now, how would you only get the FIRST line that contains Important

Comment: @KVon You have that in my answer.  Just exit the loop once you got the match, that will be the first one. So add `last;` after the print.  (This assumes that the line with `^Important` _does_ have the patterns. Otherwise, add a check.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two steps. First isolate the *Important* line from the string, and then search for the *special* substrings

Here's an example. It uses `for` as a *topicaliser*, and is essentially doing `($_) = $test =~ /^(.*Important.*)$/m`  for every occurrence of `Important`

*Note that this code will report the data from the* **last** *line containing* `Important` *if there is more than one*

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $test = <<END;
Unimportant line.
Important line with !special1! word and !special2! word. 
Extra line with !special3! word and !special4! word.
END

my @both;
@both = /!([^!]+)!/g for $test =~ /^(.*Important.*)$/m;

print join(', ', @both), "\n";
```

#### output

```
special1, special2
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this.  I think the most solid and flexible approach is to break your string into lines and iterate over that array.  Then you can choose how to select what you need and what you want to do with it, at every iteration.  For example

```
my @lines = split '\n', $test;

foreach my $line (@lines)
{
    next if $line !~ /^Important/;

    my @all_on_line = $line =~ /!(.+?)!/g;

    if (@all_on_line) 
    {
        print join(', ', @all_on_line), "\n";
    }
}
```

I assumed that `Important` is at the beginning of the wanted line. Adjust as needed. Since it is likely that more is done with data (than just print it) the `if` condition checks whether that line actually had the pattern.

Packing this into a single regex is quite a bit more involved.

Comment: This provides only to `print` the *special* strings. The OP's code generates a `@both` array with the result, and while it does `print` the contents I imagine that those strings are in fact required for further processing.

Comment: @Borodin  Somehow missed to see the comment earlier, sorry.  I know that this provides a limited answer, to (more or less) precisely what was asked, if that is what you mean.  I actually contemplated adding more, with an eye on possible further processing, but just can't see what would be generic enough, given the lack of related specifics.

Comment: No worries; I don't expect you to monitor the site 24/7! I just think that, as the OP's code generates and prints an array `@both`, it is probably best to replicate that behaviour. It's not trivial to refactor your own code to do that.

Comment: @Borodin  Right, what I meant to say is that I've been "the problem between my chair and my keyboard" for good 5 hours already but I only saw the comment now.  It sometimes happens, I just don't spot a comment (and it's annoying).

Comment: @Borodin  But I think I may not see what you are pointing at.  The OP's code for `@both` works on the right line (except that it's misnamed), but can't distinguish that line. I took the question to be that, of picking the items on only the right line.  Am I not seeing something here?

Answer (score 0):

This is also helpful with mapping function:

```
my @nwlines = map{ $_=~m/^Important(.+?(?=\!special).+?)$/mi } @lines;
```